# Find integer values of p such that $(2^p - (2^2)(3^2))/ (3^3)$ is an integer

Tags: number-theory, proof

Find integer values of p such that $(2^p - (2^2)(3^2))/ (3^3)$ is an integer.

Comment: Details are crucial.

Comment: Please edit your question to provide a complete definition of $Z$ in _Mathematica_ form. Without this we can not help.

Comment: Is this about Mathematica (the software)? If it is a math question, you should try math.stackexchange.com

Comment: You can edit your question and include some code. E.g. somethig like this finds integer numbers such that $\frac{2^p - 2^2 7^2}{3^3}$ is an integer for $1 \leq p\leq100\quad$: `Select[Table[
  p, {p, 100}], ((2^# - 2^2 7^2)/3^3) ∈ Integers &]`. However if you change `7 -> 3` you won't find any integer.

Answer (score 8):

Even though *Mathematica* has a broad range of powerful capabilites (see e.g. this comparison of [computer algebra systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_computer_algebra_systems)) in related fields (number theory, quantifier elimination) it sometimes doesn't appear to be clever enough to prove simple theorems, e.g. this should yield `False` however we get back the input:

```
Resolve[ Exists[p, p ∈ Integers && Divisible[2^p, 3]], Integers] // TraditionalForm
```

[image]

On the other hand there are examples of hard (to prove) theorems which are known to the system, e.g. [Fermat's Last Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_Last_Theorem):

```
Resolve[ Exists[{a, b, c, n}, (a | b | c | n) ∈ Integers 
         && a > 0 && b > 0 && c > 0 && n > 2 && a^n + b^n == c^n]]
```

> ```
> False
> ```

Since it is not very difficult to  prove there are no integers `p` such that `(2^p - 2^2 3^2)/3^3` is an integer let's demonstrate an appropriate mathematical proof.

Assume there exist integers $p$ and $k$, such that $$\frac{2^p - 2^2 3^2}{3^3} = k$$ i.e.
$$2^p = 27k + 36$$

The right hand side is divisible by $3$ while the left hand side is not.  QED.

Some kind of evidence of this result we can get with e.g.:

```
Select[ Range @ 100000, ((2^# - 2^2 3^2)/3^3) ∈ Integers &]
```

> ```
> {}
> ```

similarly we could demonstrate that there are no integers `p`, such that `0 < p < 10^6` satisfying the above relation, while taking e.g. `13` instead of `3` we could easily find adequate natural numbers `p <= 100`, i.e.:

```
Select[ Range @ 100, ((2^# - 2^2 13^2)/3^3) ∈ Integers &]
```

> ```
> {18, 36, 54, 72, 90}
> ```

There are slightly related problems (with $2$ and $3$ in assumptions) which might seem quite easy however they are still open see e.g. [Collatz conjecture](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CollatzProblem.html) even though it had been stated many years ago.

Answer (score 6):

We can use `Reduce` to give us:

```
expr = (2^p - (2^2) (3^2))/(3^3);

Reduce[{expr == n, n ∈ Integers}, p, Integers]
```

> ```
> (n | p) ∈ Integers && n >= -1 && p == Log2[9 (4 + 3 n)]
> ```

Since the only *x* such that `Log2[x] ∈ Integers` are powers of two, we must have `9 (4 + 3 n)` equal a power of two while `n` is simultaneously an integer.  This clearly cannot be done, since `9 (4+3n)` is divisible by `3`, whereas no power of `2` is divisible by `3`.

Answer (score 3):

How you might approach this is going to depend on your function. Here's something to get the discussion rolling. Say the function is

```
z[m_] := Sqrt[m];
```

and you wish to know what values of `m` in the range 1 to 1000 have integer-valued `z[m]`. Then you can use:

```
Position[Boole[IntegerQ /@ z[Range[1, 200]]], 1] // Flatten
```

which gives a list of all the numbers with integer square-roots.

```
{1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100, 121, 144, 169, 196, 225, 256,
 289, 324, 361, 400, 441, 484, 529, 576, 625, 676, 729, 784, 841, 900, 961}
```